# Limiting resource exhaustion on user generated queries on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am writing a public-facing query and search API where users can specify multiple conditions. These conditions will be mapped to a complex SQLAlchemy query through various filters and conditions.

What would be the best way to limit the complexity and duration of the query, so that users cannot, by accident or by purpose, cause a denial of service on the system by creating queries that take too long to process? The unsafe conditions would be 1) returning too many items once 2) the resulting query is too complex and slow and will take forever for the PostgreSQL server to evaluate. The database may return a handful or millions of items depending on the filter.

- Is implementing pagination with a fixed size `LIMIT` the only way to go or are there more advanced ways to tackle this?
- Can I add a condition on the evaluated SQL expression or SQLAlchemy session to timeout after e.g. 1 second, no matter what the query looks like?

Using PostgreSQL as the database.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT Also look at the https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html

Comment: This is so open-ended that you're going to need a VM per user if you want comprehensive protection. There are other ways to limit things, but they each have their own limitations.

Comment: Thank you @sudo - I suggest you to read the link from Abelisto. PostgreSQL 13 offers quite comprehensive run-time metering, so I think you are wrong.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I've checked those. `statement_timeout` is more of an extra layer of protection for yourself in case you mess up a query, not for protecting against potentially malicious queries. It's hard to guard against everything a user might try, and running user-provided SQL is a classic security risk. Back to timeouts, I've accidentally crashed my own database before (that is, the DB had to restart and recover from its WAL) with expensive queries that exhaust the RAM without taking very long to do so.

Comment: Thank you sudo. Just to clarify: I am not worrying about malicious queries, I am worried about resource exhaustion (mostly unintended). But I did not think about the RAM exhaustion point and will add it to my plans.

Comment: Alright, that can work. Might still be a challenge, so if you end up looking for alternatives, there are other DBs more designed for arbitrary user-specified filters.